# Mobile image cache size limitations?

Tags: android, ios, image, caching, mobile

Is anyone familiar with a comprehensive list of mobile devices and their browser's cache limits for images?

I found one reference for iPhone:

http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2008/02/iphone-cache-performance.html

But it's 3 years old. It does state, however, that the iPhone won't cache images over 25k.

I'd like to know if that's still true and if anyone has similar info for Nokia, BlackBerry and Android devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only posts I could figure out (by searching on Google) are the following:

- [Mobile Browser Cache Limits: Android, iOS, and webOS](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/06/28/mobile-browser-cache-limits/)
- [Mobile Browser Cache Limits, Revisited](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/07/12/mobile-browser-cache-limits-revisited/)
- [How Mobile Browser Cache Affects Browsing on iOS, Android, and More](http://www.tested.com/news/how-mobile-browser-cache-affects-browsing-on-ios-android-and-more/521/)

Comment: gah. Now I feel stupid. My google skills are obviously lacking. Thanks for those links!