# Broken blob image URL Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, mobile, blob

Am converting canvas image data to blob URL using below code.

```
function createBlobUrl(canvasData) {
    var binary = atob(canvasData.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    blob = new Blob([ new Uint8Array(array) ], {
        type : 'image/png'
    });
    var imgAsDataURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob, {autoRevoke: false}); 
}
```

I need to list all the images created in another page.

```
$(".imageListDiv").empty();

var html = '<ul class="list-inline list">';
for(i=0; i<blobURL.length; i++) {
    html += '<li id="' + i + '"><a';
    if (i == 0) {
        html += ' class="selected"';
    }
    html += '><img src="' + blobURL[i] + '></a></li>';
}
html += '</ul>';

$(html).appendTo(".imageListDiv");
```

But the problem am facing is in mobile browsers these URLs seems to be broken when I go back to the image list page from some other page (except the very recently created one). The preview of the image will not be available. But in desktop it is working fine.

Comment: URL objects die on page unload. Desktop browsers may be more compliant than mobile ones in what they keep in memory but what you describe is normal. Ps: `autoRevoke` parameter doesn't exists anymore, there is a `URL.createFor` in the specs, but no sure who implemented it yet.

Comment: But the last image created will be available in the list in another page and others are broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobile image cache size limitations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997798/mobile-image-cache-size-limitations)